# Jupyter notebook is giving me error for correct codes

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

My jupyter notebook is giving error for codes that are correct. specifically this is my error: `AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘plot’`

I have check and check again, i have re written my codes, i also ran my code cell by cell and also use `Run all`. but not working. Your help will sincerely be appreciated.

here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

recent_grads = pd.read_csv("recent-grads.csv")
cleaned_data_count = recent_grads.count()
print (cleaned_data_count)
```

This is my error output

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e0fa232c36bf> in <module>
      1 # Look up the number of rows to ascertain if data has been droped
----> 2 cleaned_data_count = recent_grads.count()
      3 print (cleaned_data_count)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
```

my plot also gives error.
Here is the code for my plot

```
recent_grads.plot(x="Sample_size", y="Median", kind = "scatter", title = "Sample_size VS Median")
recent_grads.plot(x="Sample_size", y="Unemployment_rate", kind = "scatter", title = "Sample_size VS Uemployemny")
recent_grads.plot(x="Full_time", y="Median", kind = "scatter", title = "Full_time VS Median")
recent_grads.plot(x="ShareWomen", y="Unemployment_rate", kind = "scatter", title = "Sharewoman VS Unemployment_rate")
recent_grads.plot(x="Men",y="Median", kind = "scatter", title = "Men VS Median")
recent_grads.plot(x="Women",y="Median", kind = "scatter", title = "Sample_size VS Median")
```

here is my plot error output

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-6d7d435b7c0f> in <module>
----> 1 recent_grads.plot(x="Sample_size", y="Median", kind = "scatter", title = "Sample_size VS Median")
      2 recent_grads.plot(x="Sample_size", y="Unemployment_rate", kind = "scatter", title = "Sample_size VS Uemployemny")
      3 recent_grads.plot(x="Full_time", y="Median", kind = "scatter", title = "Full_time VS Median")
      4 recent_grads.plot(x="ShareWomen", y="Unemployment_rate", kind = "scatter", title = "Sharewoman VS Unemployment_rate")
      5 recent_grads.plot(x="Men",y="Median", kind = "scatter", title = "Men VS Median")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

here is my screenshoot
[code and error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMfP7.png)
[code and error screenshot for plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb7SR.png)

Comment: I would start with checking the contents of  `recent_grads = pd.read_csv("recent-grads.csv") ` since there is nothing in the variable `recent_grads`

Comment: `print(recent_grads)` and see what you get?

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace precisely indicates the offending row:

```
----> 2 cleaned_data_count = recent_grads.count()
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Apparently *recent_grads* is *None*, so you can't invoke any method on it,
including *count* (and *plot* which you attempt to invoke later).

So there is probably something wrong with *read_csv* in the previous instruction.
I suppose that the input file exists, otherwise another exception would
have been thrown earlier. Maybe this file is empty?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The file is not empty. When i `print (recent_grads)` , expected result is given.